# Suggestions for hosting Java EE App.(Tomcat,Glassfish) and Postgis

Tags: hosting, tomcat, postgis

Which company offers the best services for hosting the above app?(Preferable tomcat and postgis)

Answer (score 1):

For Java hosting services with the choice of Tomcat, JBoss, or GlassFish Java application servers try [eApps Hosting](http://www.eapps.com/applications/application-hosting-index.php)